# Most efficient way to automatically name photos according to a naming convention?

Tags: windows, automation, rename, filenames, batch-rename

I am a solar site assessor and am subcontracting for a company that uses a specific naming convention for all photographs taken at sites.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to efficiently adhere to this naming convention and avoid a bunch of ultra-tedious and time consuming copying and pasting.

I've been separating photos into folders based on what they depict and then using [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) within those folders, but this is a stopgap measure at best.  I feel there must be a more efficient way to go about this.

I've been using a digital camera on the site, downloading them to a computer, and sorting them from there.  Is there possibly an app that would sort photos taken on a smartphone or tablet as I take them in the field?

I'm using Windows 10.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Linux, Unix, Macintosh, Windows, other?

Comment: Edited.  I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I can create a one step batch for you but I'll need to see and example of the name you desire (before/after). regarding the app idea, the saving/sorting is handled by the Camera app it self and replacing that would be a bad idea because it may affect the quality of your pictures. you'll need a 2nd app for sorting and renaming.

Comment: We need an example or two of the specific naming convention you have to adhere to. How much of that convention is contained in the photo's exif info? Sounds like Windows 10 matter only if you can't do it on your smartphone or tablet, correct? Android, Apple, or other?